# Https Communication to Java Server with Dotnet Client

Tags: c#, https, communication, .net

I need to send financial messages(transactions) to a bank with the help of `HTTPS` communication. Bank server is written on `Java` while my application is in `.Net`.

Following are only details I received from their side:

> Https request:
>   • The entire ISO request for https should be sent as an attachment to the following
>   servlet:
>   https:///Servlet/IBSOtherVendorRequestServlet

What are other components or documents required from their side and which `namespace` of `.Net` can I use for this communication?

Kindly help me on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know how to query the servlet : SOAP ? REST ? what are the parameters and which method should be used ? result in plain text, XML or JSON ?

It looks like you have to POST a request to this Servlet. You have to know what is an "entire ISO request" then POST it to this url using HttpClient or HttpWebRequest. It will probably look like this : [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)

Comment: Thanks for you update. Kindly confirm method defined in link shared by you communication is inter-opertable. As per my knowledge web service is used for inter-operatable transactions as it send details in soap but here is no use of soap and we are sending memory stream in bytes format so not sure whether it will work

Comment: If this is a SOAP web service, it will be easier with WCF. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976044/implementing-a-soap-client-in-c-sharp-with-wcf-and-net-4-0 in both cases it is inter-operable.